# how can i solve laravel Homestead error 500

Tags: laravel, homestead

After multiple tries to install Homestead and create Laravel project, I did it and created a local host called myprokarezma.test.

But, when I access this domain locally, I get "error 500" in the layout of Laravel , which means that homestead is connected to the Laravel project.

I don't know the reason of error 500, It was supposed to display a welcome message as I saw in tutorial videos.

**stacktrace** :

> production.ERROR: Declaration of
>   Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale)
>   must be compatible with
>   Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string
>   $locale) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 64):
>   Declaration of
>   Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale)
>   must be compatible with
>   Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string
>   $locale) at
>   /home/vagrant/code/laravel-5.8-master/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php:24)

[image]

Comment: Check what `storage/logs/laravel.log` tells you…

Comment: do you mean to open the file or open the path in the browser ?, sorry but this is my first laravel project

Comment: production.ERROR: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 64): Declaration of Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\\Contracts\\Translation\\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) at /home/vagrant/code/laravel-5.8-master/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php:24)
[stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"`
to the `composer.json` file

and then run
`composer update` in the terminal